# How to get the frequency array and extract a range of frequency from wav file

Tags: r, audio

```
readWave('hello.wav',from=0,to=1,units='seconds')
plot(hello@left,xlab="time",ylab="freq")
```

But how to get the frequency array before applying short-time fourier transform and take out a specific range of the frequency in R? For example, [60,300] Hz for adult men and save it as another wav. file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a frequency band-pass filter. The package `seewave` has a suitable function, `fir`, ([and a lot of other useful things](http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/)).

```
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

hello <- readWave("hello.wav")

hello.bp <- fir(hello, from=60, to=300, output="Wave")
hello.bp <- normalize(hello.bp, unit=as.character(hello.bp@bit))
meanspec(hello.bp, log="x")
writeWave(hello.bp, "hello.bp.wav")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Because the human voice frequency range is about [0,300]Hz, after narrowed down the range, "Hello" sounded like "ur-ah". Are the frequencies stand for different things?

Comment: The fundamental frequency of human speech lies at around 60-300Hz, but most of the 'voice' is contained in the [formants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant), the upper harmonics, and they extend to at least 5000Hz. Change the bandpass to f.ex. [500-5000] and you should be capturing enough of the frequencies to make the speech intelligible.